# Makes service worker to save all details pages offline before having to visit them

Tags: javascript, vite, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I've setup some offline capabilities with vitePWA on my react PWA.

I've got a bunch of details ( `/details/:id` ) pages which I want to be accessed offline.

If I visit thoses pages at least once, the service worker will catch the api call of the details and all differents asset that the page needs...

Here is my vitePWA conf and sw.js :

```js
VitePWA({
      strategies: 'injectManifest',
      injectManifest: {
        globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,jsx,css,html,png,svg,woff2,ico,json,webp}'],
      },
      devOptions: {
        enabled: false,
        type: 'module',
        // Include index.html in __WB_MANIFEST in development
        navigateFallback: 'index.html',
      },
      manifest: {
       ...
      }
```

sw.js :

```js
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import { NavigationRoute, registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';
import {
  cleanupOutdatedCaches,
  createHandlerBoundToURL,
  precacheAndRoute,
} from 'workbox-precaching';
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies';
import { CacheableResponsePlugin } from 'workbox-cacheable-response';
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration';

// Register precached routes (static cache)
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST || []);

// Clean prievous cache with different "version"
cleanupOutdatedCaches();

// Install directly the sw
self.skipWaiting();

// Makes the sw to control already open tabs of the website !
clientsClaim();

// Cache other routes than index :
// This assumes /index.html has been precached (by precacheAndRoute).
const handler = createHandlerBoundToURL('/index.html');
const navigationRoutes = new NavigationRoute(handler, {
  allowlist: [new RegExp('/details/')],
  denylist: [new RegExp('/edit')],
});
registerRoute(navigationRoutes);

// Cache server calls (StaleWhileRevalidate)
registerRoute(
  ({ url, sameOrigin }) => url.pathname.match(/^\/api\/canOffLine\//),
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'api-offline',
    plugins: [
      new ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 10,
        maxAgeSeconds: 31536000,
      }),
      new CacheableResponsePlugin({
        statuses: [0, 200],
      }),
    ],
  }),
  'GET'
);
```

But how can I trigger ( with a button click ? ) the saving of all the differents pages details locally ?

I've tried to open all the differents pages once in a pop-up windows with a specific search param to "auto-close" them but it seems very hacky !

ugly "solution" :

```js
allDetailsIds.forEach((id) =>
  window.open(`http://mywebsite/details/${id}?autoClose=true`, '_blank', 'popup=1')
);

// And on the main page : 
const [params] = useSearchParams();

useEffect(() => {
  if (params.get('autoClose') === 'true') {
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.close();
      }, 400);
  }
}, []);
```

Is there a proper way ?